# Remove duplicate rows by checking mutliple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

TABLE 1:

```
ID  NAME  AGE
1   A1   24
2   A2   25
3   A3   27
4   A4   28
5   A1   24
6   A6   27
7   A3   27
8   B1   21
9   B1   22
```

Need to remove duplicate combinations of name and age (Eg. A1-24 , A3-27..etc) in SQL..
Distinct is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you may want to aggregate the ID column, you can go with:

```
select min(`ID`)
  ,`NAME`
  ,`AGE`
from `test_duplicates`
group by 2,3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result set to still have all three columns, then you need to provide logic regarding which `ID` value to retain.  Assuming you want the smallest `ID` value we can try:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, NAME, AGE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME, AGE;
```

If you don't need the `ID` column, then in fact a distinct select should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, AGE
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the `IDs`

```
SELECT "ID" FROM
RANK() Over (partition by "NAME" Order by "AGE") as "rank"
FROM "YourTable" as "data") as "derived_table"
Where "rank" = 1`
```

Example is in Postgresql

Answer (score 1):

example for MS SQL Server
to select:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, NAME, AGE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,AGE ORDER BY NAME,AGE) row_num
     FROM  Table1
)

SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

if you want to delete the duplicate rows change the select with :

```
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8b2cc/8)